# mongoose query wont be modified

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Im struggeling to increase the value of my chance.
For some reason, it wont modify it, i think it has something to do with the line within the `$inc` .

Here is my code:

```
var location: 1,
option = 1,
t = option - 1,
increase = 500;




 easyCrime.update({userid: playerid, "locations.location" : location, "locations.location.easycrime.id" : option }, {"$inc" : {"locations.$.location.easycrime[t].chance" : increase}}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

result:

```
 { ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }
```

why isnt this modified?

model:

```
userid: {
                    type: String,
                    default: '57c1c0f3b6b20c011242bf22'
                },


 locations: [
        {
            userid: {
                type: String,
                default: '57c1c0f3b6b20c011242bf22'
            },
            location: {
                type: Number,
                default: 1
            },
            easycrime: [
                {
                    optioname : {
                        type: String,
                        default: 'text'
                    },
                    chance: {
                        type: Number,
                        default: 200
                    },
                    id : {
                        type: Number,
                        default: 1,
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
```

EDIT:

found out that locations.location.easycrime dont exist.
updated code to:

```
easyCrime.update({userid: playerid, "locations.location" : location, "locations.easycrime.id" : option }, {"$inc" : {"locations.$.easycrime[0].chance" : increase}}).then(function (result) {
            console.log("inserted chance");
            console.log(result);
            return resolve(result);
        });
```

but still wont work     `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

EDIT 2:

tried the following query:

```
var location: 1,
option = 1,
t = option - 1,
increase = 500;
      console.log("updating chance " + increase);
easyCrime.update({userid: playerid, "locations.location" : location, "locations.easycrime.id" : option }, {$inc : {"locations.$.easycrime.$.chance" : increase}}).then(function (result) {
           console.log("inserted chance");
    console.log(result);
});
```

but   `console.log("inserted chance");` and `console.log(result);` wont be executed. ( means, it wouldnt run)

Comment: under the model, you find locations, and in locations you find easycrime. thats atleast what i want. @Aruna , i saw the mistake, but not sure if it would fix it.

Comment: @Aruna, updated thread.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer for few other suggestions

Comment: Also, please change `"$inc"` to `$inc` without quotes. I have updated the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks `easycrime` at `locations.location.easycrime` where it exists at `locations.easycrime` in your model. I have modified it.

Also `locations.easycrime` is an array, so you should use `locations.$.easycrime.$.chance` instead of `locations.$.easycrime[t].chance`.

Also noticed, you query looks for `option` but updating it with `t`. Make the both same as below.

```
var location: 1,
option = 1,
t = option - 1,
increase = 500;

easyCrime.update({userid: playerid, "locations.location" : location, "locations.easycrime.id" : option }, {$inc : {"locations.$.easycrime.$.chance" : increase}}).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: it wont be executed when i try.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/d6uy3e result:   increasing chance
    updating chance 500 .. and nothing more.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you tried? I will create a sample for this and will try the same shortly :-)

Comment: Thanks @Aruna i look forward to IT

Comment: @maria can you advise me what you tried in the `$inc` block. Just want to double check whether it is, `{$inc : {"locations.$.easycrime.$.chance" : increase}}`

Comment: Yes IT was excactly that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128011/discussion-between-aruna-and-maria).

Comment: Ah okay, I just seen the Edit 2. Thanks

Comment: @maria Please bear with me. I am still creating a sample app for this and crosses few hurdles

Comment: wanna chat @Aruna ?

Answer (score 1):

try this should work

```
 var location: 1,
    option = 1,
    t = option - 1,
    increase = 500;
var updateChance={};
updateChance["locations.$.easycrime."+t+".chance"] = increase;

easyCrime.update({userid: playerid, "locations.location" : location,    "locations.easycrime.id" : option }, {$inc : updateChance }).then(function (result) {
       console.log("inserted chance");
console.log(result);
});
```